# How to format a cell based on the the cell above it?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of dates in ascending order, with quite a few duplicates, and I want to bold the first one of every unique date. (e.g. **May 1st**, May 1st, **May 2nd**, **May 3rd**, May 3rd)

I wanted to bold another column based on the last unique one in this one and was able to achieve it after a little research by simply using the formula `=$A1 < $A2`. That idea doesn't seem to work here though as `=$A1 > $A0` gives an error message. How do you do this?

Edit: I'm using Excel 2007.

Comment: The cell reference `A0` is invalid, because there is no zero-th row in Excel. Try to add a header row in order to supress the overflow.

Comment: Are you using Excel 2007, or an older product?

Comment: @Howard: That's what I assumed, but the header idea didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the dates are contained in the cells `A2`, `A3`, `A4`... (due to the nature of the formula we need a header line and thus `A1` is not in the range). The column you want to format is column `B`.

- select cells `B2` to `B?`
- capture conditional formatting with formula `=$A2<>$A1`

Now only the first unique line (based on criterion in column `A`) is formatted differently.

Comment: @Ullallulloo Not for me. Note that for the condition I selected line 2 and the formula refers to A2 and A1 (i.e. the line above).

Comment: Okay, it works for me now, but it changed the formula to `=$A1<>$A1048576`. I can apply it to `$A:$A`, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Excel 2007, you can use Conditional Formatting (a style button off of the Home tab).

- Select the dates as a range.
- Conditional Formatting -> New Rules.
- Choose "Format only unique or duplicate values"
- Format all pulldown: Choose "duplicate" values in the selected range.
- On the Font tab, Select Bold under Font style.
- Press OK twice.

This will bold all of the duplicated dates.

EDIT: OP really wants the first of all unique values. Here is a way to do that (without an extra column).

- Select the second date (A2)
- Conditional Formatting -> New Rules.
- Choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
- Enter formula `=$A2<>$A1` . The dollar signs are important.
- On the Font tab, Select Bold under Font style.
- Press OK twice.
- Use the format painter to copy the Conditional Formatting from A2 to the last date.
- Format A1 as bold, as it will always be unique.

Comment: That formats all duplicates, I want to only format the first one, and any unique values.

Comment: OK, thanks, you DID state that in the question. Here's a fix. In cell B1, place a "1". In B2, place a formula =B2-B1. Fill-down the formula to the row of the last date. B will now have 0 next to a dup and 1 next to a unique date. Now select the dates and Conditionally Format, but based on "Use a formula to determine which cells to format." For the formula, enter "=b1>0", to use the column you just created. Then choose your Bold format. This bolded all my unique dates but not the duplicated dates.

Comment: Yeah, but that's kind of a hack. Apparently, if you enter `$A1048576` instead of `$A0`, it'll loop over again.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach is to use the following for the Conditional Formatting formula:

```
(A1<>INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row")-1,CELL("col"),1)))
```